# Change Data field

Tags: azure-databricks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdWr7.jpg)I am trying to do the change data field and type changes.Refer below the script:

```py
## To Get the Version changes of data in delta tables
delta_df = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM table_changes('TableName',1) order by _commit_timestamp")
display(delta_df)
```

In table_changes('TableName',1) Instead of 1 I need to  mention the latest version.How it can done.

Regards
Rohit

Comment: Have you tried any approach/effort? Share the blockers/errors that occurred during the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spark.sql("DESCRIBE HISTORY <tablename>").collect()[0][0]` to collect the latest version of the table. Store this in a variable and use it instead of `1` in the code.

**Code:**

```py
max_version = spark.sql("DESCRIBE HISTORY <tablename>").collect()[0][0]
delta_df = spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM table_changes('<tablename>',{max_version}) order by _commit_timestamp")
display(delta_df)
```

I tried this for a sample table and checked history of that using `Describe History <table_name>` command.

[image]

Then used the above code and got the latest version details.

[image]

Comment: I have one more requirement. I need to include the column "_commit_timestamp"  into <tablename>  how  the new column can be created in existing column

Comment: Not able to find the Mark this is an answer option

Comment: To accept an answer, click the "checkmark" button underneath the vote buttons in above answer. Refer this [image](https://i.imgur.com/4DnXPJu.png)

Comment: With this query :delta_df = spark.sql(f"SELECT * FROM table_changes('<tablename>',{max_version}) order by _commit_timestamp")  not able to get the records if i remove f' then it will be date error. please advise

Comment: What did you remove?

Comment: I have changed little bit query max_version = spark.sql("DESCRIBE HISTORY <tablename>")
Max=max_version.collect()[0][0] but still not able to read the 1st row .it is giving  "Query returned no results"  Please advise how i can read the 1st row data

Comment: What do u get when you run this command `DESCRIBE HISTORY <tablename>`

Comment: it will get the lists of data there are around 14 version rows records .I need to get latest version 14

Comment: `max_version = spark.sql("DESCRIBE HISTORY <tablename>").collect()[0][0]` Can you check what is the value stored in max_version

Comment: max_version = spark.sql("DESCRIBE HISTORY <tablename>").collect()[0][0] i am getting "Query returned no results"

Comment: Could you provide screenshot? With the query and result

Comment: Please refer the link                      https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdWr7.jpg

Comment: Share other screenshots also .. 1) `DESCRIBE HISTORY <tablename>`
2)`max_version = spark.sql("DESCRIBE HISTORY <tablename>").collect()[0][0] 
  print (max_version)`